# Windows Kiosk mode - Allow cookies in MS Edge?

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge, cookies, kiosk, mode

I enabled on "interactive display" machine with Windows 10 Pro the Kiosk mode with MS Edge running an web application. I also set that the app should restart every 5 minutes of inactivity.

The problem is, that this application on every restart clears cookies and shows the GDPR cookie consent alert, because the MS Edge is in "InPrivate mode". My customer find this alert annoying and want me to get rid of it.

I tried to disable "InPrivate mode" under gpedit.msc, but that doesn't seem to work.
I also tried to communicate with developers of the app currently running on the kiosk, but they cannot update their application just for us.

There's also another option I tried and it was to use normal Windows with my custom batch script, but the app running there uses Windows integrated on-screen keyboard, which I couldn't get to work after killing the explorer.exe process. After running TabTip.exe manually it showed the keyboard, but after pressing the text input in the app, nothing happened.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you should be able to run a second icognito mode window in the background, which does not restart. In Edge / chromium, cookies are shared between concurrent incognito mode windows.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is a limitation of using Kiosk mode on Windows at this time; there is currently no way to disable In Private mode while using Kiosk mode.

Another consideration would be to use an extension that hides these cookie banners by default. However, the Kiosk mode also does not support this.

You can read more about what isn't supported here;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-configure-kiosk-mode#functional-limitations